# is there no pre-baked Android Dialog prompt?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I just realized that I don't see a way to collect a string from the user in a simple, pre-packaged Dialog prompt.  Am I overlooking something or do I really need to write a custom Dialog to perform this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I would use an AlertDialog and create a new EditText.
Hand it to the Dialog with .setView and handle the text in the onClick-Events.

```
  final EditText prompt = new EditText(this);
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);
  builder.setTitle("My fancy title");
  builder.setView(prompt);
  builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      String myText = prompt.getText().toString();
    }
  });
  AlertDialog promptDialog = builder.create();
  promptDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

check this link

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

the idea is to use dialog.setContentView(), and make ur own layout there

Answer (score 1):

You don't have this type of `Dialog` in the `SDK` but it is pretty simple to make one with the `AlertDialog` and his [`setView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29) method.